# TFS Add a folder but now the files or folder contained within it

Tags: version-control, tfs, directory-structure

I have a mapping as follows

```
$/Root/App/Folder
```

mapped to `C:\Root\App\Folder`

in `C:\Root\App\Folder` I have an existing folder called `New` that I want to add to source control but I don't want to add the files (or sub folders) contained within it

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I use [TFS Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) for adding folder structures to source control because it works easy and fine with the windows explorer.

The mapped folders get a little green icon, only right click on new folder and select "Team Foundation Server" and "Add".

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a "one level mapping" (using an asterix) - this will map the folder, and all the sub-files under it, but not the sub-folders. Once you've setup the workspace mapping, then you can add just the folder to TFS - everything else will be ignored.

For example, your workspace mappings would look like this:

```
$/Root/App/Folder  -->  C:\Root\App\Folder
$/Root/App/Folder/New/* --> C:\Root\App\Folder\New
```

For more information, see this blog post on [Workspace Mapping Improvements in TFS 2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tfsvcs/archive/2006/12/28/orcas-workspace-mapping-improvements.aspx)